# ¿Como cambiar de texto plano a PDF?

Tags: php, laravel, curl

tengo un problema; en el postman hice pruebas con un enlace de Truora y me devolvía un pdf con antecedentes penales ahora lo que busco es hacerlo en laravel pero me devuelve texto plano similar a esto: "j����G���mOyP5���e�t��~]�C���� a��׆�����7" como haría para que me devuelva un pdf. Gracias.

Adjunto el fragmento de código que estoy usando para traer el pdf.

```
        $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.checks.truora.com/v1/checks/'.$_GET['check_id'].'/pdf',
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                'Truora-API-Key: ***'
            ),
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);

        curl_close($curl);
        return $response;
```

Answer (score -1):

Ya lo resolví, cambié ese fragmento del código

```
        $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 
        'https://api.checks.truora.com/v1/checks/'.$_GET['check_id'].'/pdf');
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Truora-API-Key: ***'
        ));

        header('Content-type: application/pdf');

        $response = curl_exec($curl);

        curl_close($curl);
        echo $response;
```

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido a la comunidad. Que bueno que encontraste solución a tu pregunta. Te recomiendo que edites tu respuesta y pongas un poco más de información explicando la solución para que otros usuarios con la misma pregunta puedan entenderla. Recuerda que las buenas respuestas se diferencian de las excelentes por los detalles. Saludos!

Comment: También recuerda aceptar la respuesta, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas.